# How to add link within if-statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, hyperlink

I have some problems to put a URL-function within an if-statement properly. The following method works fine outside of my if-statement and the newly created link refers to this URL: "h**p://www.blog.com/?location=Bern&date=1"

```
<?php $rasp = $_GET["location"]; ?>
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\])."&date=0"; ?> " >Heutel</a>
```

If-Statement works also just fine when I put simply an URL (e.g. https://www.google.com/) in between the quotation marks, then if I put the URL-function above in there, the newly created link refers to this: "h**p://www.blog.com/%3C?php%20echo%20preg_replace%28". Actually it should refer to the URL above "h**p://www.blog.com/?location=Bern&date=1"

URL-Function within if-statement:

```
<?php $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url,'date=1')) { echo 

'<?php $rasp = $_GET["location"]; ?>
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\])."&date=0"; ?> " >Heutel</a> ' ;


} else {
 echo 'No cars.';
}  ?>
```

Any ideas?

Solution thanks to IMSop:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url,'date=1')) {
?>
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=0"; ?> " >Heutel</a>
<?php
} 

else {
 echo 'No cars.';
}
```

Comment: What is `$_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\])`??

Comment: @PeeHaa OP probably meant to escape double quotes which evidently aren't in there. That's my take on it.

Comment: Start by changing `$_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\]` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` --- for one thing. Or if you meant to escape double quotes, should read as `$_SERVER[\"REQUEST_URI\"]` or `$_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']`

Comment: that's for ignoring the apostrophes inside echo' ', otherwise I get a parse error.

Comment: @user2039237 You'll need to do one of my suggestions. You can't just put \ with nothing to escape with.

Comment: @user2039237 But in the example you paste, you've missed out the apostrophes - you wanted `[\'REQUEST_URI\']`.

Comment: @user2039237 You will need to try a few combinations. Quotes can be quite tricky at times. However you can't leave `$_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\]` the way it is.

Comment: Well, thanks. I thought it was right that way, looked it up here: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/595-php-parse-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-or - they tell

`echo 'we don't know';`  should be written as `echo 'we don\t know';`

Comment: @user2039237 yes, using a \ to escape a single quote needs to be one in order to show an apostrophe inside single quoted echoes. However it's not needed when an echo is encased in double quotes.

Comment: @user2039237 That example is wrong (or is displaying wrong on the page for some reason); it would be `echo 'we don\'t know';` not `echo 'we don\t know';`

Answer (score 1):

This sequence makes no sense:

```
echo '<a href="<?php echo ...
```

A quoted string and direct output outside the `<?php ... ?>` markers are completely different things. The `'` starts a string, which will continue until you put another `'`; the `<?php` would start a block of PHP code if you weren't in one, but you already are - if you weren't the `echo` wouldn't mean anything.

To join multiple strings together, you can use the `.` ("concatenation") operator:

```
echo '<a href="' . preg_replace(...) . '">>Heutel</a>';
```

Alternatively, drop out of PHP mode like you were before, but with the `if` in place:

```
<?php 
// In PHP mode...
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url,'date=1')) {
// Now leaving PHP mode, but still inside the if condition...
?>
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=0"; ?> " >Heutel</a>
<?php
// Re-enter PHP mode to close off the if statement
}
```

There's even an [alternative syntax for control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which some people prefer to use in cases like this:

```
<?php 
if ($some_condition) :
?>
your output here
<?php
endif;
?>
```

which is exactly the same as

```
<?php 
if ($some_condition) {
?>
your output here
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: $_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\\] is bad ?

Comment: @jacouh Did you mean that comment as an answer to PeeHaa's comment on the question? I didn't even mention that in my answer.

Comment: @jacouh It should read as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` --- `$_SERVER[\REQUEST_URI\]` is indeed not correct.

Comment: @jacouh I'm confused. I didn't even spot it, although I've now corrected it in my example for good measure. Were you trying to point it out to me? You phrased (or, at least, punctuated) your comment as a question, and I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yeah thanks for now. I try this out with $_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\'] which Frank suggested.

Comment: @user2039237 You shouldn't need to escape any apostrophes here, because you don't want to output the literal string `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you want to use that variable in the PHP code (as an argument to `echo` or `preg_replace`). The escaping was **not** the main problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice IMSoP. I wanted to share my solution with you, I used that interlaced method from IMSoP. Thanks for the effort! unfortunately I cannot answer it, I will reedit my post soon.

`<?php 
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (false !== strpos($url,'date=1')) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=0"; ?> " >Heutel</a>
    <?php
    } 
   
    else {
     echo 'No cars.';
    }`